# How to correctly define index aliases in Modx/xPDO models?

Tags: mysql, modx, xpdo

I have a couple of tables that relate to each other in a couple of different ways in my model, a table for fund requests that will both refer to the Entity table for a client and an employer - so it needs 2 indexes, what is the correct way to set up the XML model schema?

Here are the tables [drastically shortened!]:

```
<object class="FundRequest" table="fund_request" extends="xPDOSimpleObject">
    <field key="token" dbtype="varchar" precision="50" phptype="string" null="true" />
    <field key="unixtime" dbtype="varchar" precision="50" phptype="string" null="true" />

    <field ... a bunch of fields not related to the question... />

    <field key="payee_uid" dbtype="int" precision="8" phptype="integer" null="true" />
    <field key="client_uid" dbtype="int" precision="8" phptype="integer" null="false" />

    <aggregate alias="Entities" class="Entities" local="payee_uid" foreign="id" cardinality="one" owner="foreign" />
    <aggregate alias="Entities" class="Entities" local="client_uid" foreign="id" cardinality="one" owner="foreign" />
</object>

<object class="Entities" table="entities" extends="xPDOSimpleObject">
    <field key="token" dbtype="varchar" precision="50" phptype="string" null="true" />
    <field key="unixtime" dbtype="varchar" precision="50" phptype="string" null="true" />

    <field ... a bunch of fields not related to the question... />

    <aggregate alias="FundRequest" class="FundRequest" foreign="payee_uid" local="id" cardinality="one" owner="local" />
    <aggregate alias="FundRequest" class="FundRequest" foreign="client_uid" local="id" cardinality="one" owner="local" />
</object>
```

I'm thinking I should be naming my aggregate aliases in the FundRequest tables as:

```
<aggregate alias="PayeeEntity" class="Entities" local="payee_uid" foreign="id" cardinality="one" owner="foreign" />
<aggregate alias="ClientEntity" class="Entities" local="client_uid" foreign="id" cardinality="one" owner="foreign" />
```

So I can refer to them as

```
$object->FundRequest->PayeeEntity->get('whatever');
```

in my code.

A) Is this correct?

B) How Should I label my aliases in the Entities table?

C) I think the alias types are correct, neither record in either table should get deleted if the other is removed.

Comment: MODX Revo doesn't operate xml schemes. It uses map files. The best solution is in generating them from you tables in db via CMPGenerator extra.
This method solve all your problems: A,B and C

Comment: CMPGenerator will not create your indexes for you, you have to create them yourself. CMPGenerator actually does create an XML schema then generates the map & class files from that. If you need table relationships defined [or aliases] you need to edit that XML schema.

Comment: About indexes. Of course you should do it manually. PhpMyAdmin is best tool for it. Also it doesn't create relations for you. But you should create them also in XML scheme manually (as in creating maps).
I suppose you are generating schemes to generate maps. Am i right? In this case they are unnecessary.
You can create your custom db with indexes and after all generate map for modx. CMPGenerator also generates xml 4 u(without relations of course).

When you are creating maps this way you can be sure that all data types will be right.

Answer (score 1):

> so it needs 2 indexes

In fact you tables may not have mysql indexes (maybe only `PRIMARY` index to improve speed when you are working with xpdo objects) at all and it will work. But with indexes requests will work faster.

When you work on architecture of you db you should analyze what kind of data will be stored and in what way you want get the data.

Let's analize you scheme.

> `<aggregate alias="Entities" class="Entities" local="payee_uid" foreign="id" cardinality="one" owner="foreign" />
>   <aggregate alias="Entities" class="Entities" local="client_uid" foreign="id" cardinality="one" owner="foreign" />`

This is very strange and i suppose wrong. Also i start to think that you are muddled in indexes and aggregate/composite relations (i'll later call them `Relations`). They are not the same.

`Relations` allows you to make a realtion between `XPDO` objects. And `XPDO` uses this mechanism to save and get `related objects`.

`Indexes` are usefull for db. They help to improve speed of requests and to control data (for ex. `UNIQUE` index means that current field (or couple of fields) should have uniqie value/combination of values)

### Let's talk about `Relations`.

So, every `xpdo` object has internal property `_relatedObjects`. So it's very powerfull thing in `XPDO`. And relations allows to do this (it's rather simple example):

```
$u = $modx->newObject('modUser');
$p = $modx->newObject('modUserProfile');

$u->fromArray(…);
$p->fromArray(…);

$u->Profile = $p;
$u->save();
```

When you assign `$p` to `->Profile` setter does all work 4 u and in the end we have profile object at `_relatedObjects`. `XPDO` uses them for saving. This is a little bit complex but in short `XPDO` saves `relatedObjects` twice to keep keys and after all save needed object (`modUser` in our case).
In the end all fields that we use for `Relations` will be set correctly.

#### About relation fields:

- alias — name of relation
- class — xpdo object's class
- local - primary key field in local object
- foreign - secondary key field in related object
- cardinality — type of relation
- owner — owner of key

---

### About naming

When you try to create name for `Relations` your hands are free. But anyway they should be nice to understand the relation.

How i'm doing that:
The best source for name is you db table name. If i'm developing a package for modx i also use it's name for tables.

Table names:

- modx_package_obj
- modx_package_secondobj
- modx_package_obj_secondobj

Now we want to get maps for modx (i don't use schemes cause they are not needed for modx).

CMPGenerator helps me to create maps.
Now we have objects:

- PackageObj (id,name)
- PackageSecondobj (id)
- PackageObjSecondobj (id, obj_id, sobj_id)

Cause my test objects should have relation via `PackageObjSecondobj` i need relations.

`$xpdo_meta_map['PackageObj']= array (
  …
  'composites' =>
  array (
    'ObjSecondobj' =>
    array (
      'class' => 'PackageObjSecondobj',
      'local' => 'id',
      'foreign' => 'obj_id',
      'owner' => 'local',
      'cardinality' => 'many',
    ),
  ),
);
$xpdo_meta_map['PackageSecondobj']= array (
  …
  'composites' =>
  array (
    'ObjSecondobj' =>
    array (
      'class' => 'PackageObjSecondobj',
      'local' => 'id',
      'foreign' => 'sobj_id',
      'owner' => 'local',
      'cardinality' => 'many',
    ),
  ),
);
$xpdo_meta_map['PackageObjSecondobj']= array (
  …
  'aggregates' =>
  array (
    'Obj' =>
    array (
      'class' => 'PackageObj',
      'local' => 'obj_id',
      'foreign' => 'id',
      'owner' => 'foreign',
      'cardinality' => 'one',
    ),
    'Secondobj' =>
    array (
      'class' => 'PackageSecondobj',
      'local' => 'sobj_id',
      'foreign' => 'id',
      'owner' => 'foreign',
      'cardinality' => 'one',
    ),
  ),
);`

So, as you see, package name + obj name for xpdo objects, obj name for `Relations`. It's quite simple, easy to understand and very usefull.

---

Let's return to your example.
You have two tables and create relation to each other twice. That's very messy and won't work predictable. Also we might have troubles while saving objects.

I don't know your task and problem, which you try to solve, but can say exactly that you are doing wrong.

You can describe your task properly and maybe i can help.

### UPD

As i understand you have Payees and Clients. Payee may be a client and may be not.

In this case `FundRequest->Payee` and `FundRequest->Client` relations would be nice.

Also `Payee` and `Client` should be **independent objects** and they may have relations.